# Depends drop down default CakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, cakephp

While creating an invoice I want to be able to set the default value of a drop down list of currencies depending on the selected customers home currency but i still want to be able to change this default by selecting another currency.

For example i have my currencies table with all available currencies

[image]

Customers table with their preferred currencies.
[image]

And lastly the invoice table with the currency used
[image]

For example when this customer is selected I want the currency to change to AUD but i want to still be able to change it.
[image]

Not quite sure where to start with this i anyone could give any clues that would be great thanks.

Here's the code for my view file add.ctp

```
<div class="invoices form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($invoice) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Invoice') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('customer_id', ['options' => $customers, 'empty' => true,'id'=>'customers']);
            echo $this->Form->input('currency_id', ['options' => $currencies, 'default'=> 1]);
        ?>

    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Here is my add function in my InvoiceController.

```
public function add()
    {
        $invoice = $this->Invoices->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $invoice = $this->Invoices->patchEntity($invoice, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Invoices->save($invoice)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The invoice has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The invoice could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $customers = $this->Invoices->Customers->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $currencies = $this->Invoices->Currencies->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);

        $this->set(compact('invoice', 'customers', 'users', 'customerContacts', 'aircraftRegistrations', 'shippingCompanies', 'supervisingEngineerUsers', 'jobTypes', 'openedByUsers', 'assignedToUsers', 'currencies'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['invoice']);
    }
```

Comment: For starters, you should show the code that generates that drop down list (and the sql information on how you are currently fetching it). It is very clear what you want (+1), but this question lacks the information to resolve the question with 1 answer (-1). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47319102/edit) the question to insert the necessary information.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Xorifelse just made some edits.